# Unable to fake terminal input with termios.TIOCSTI

Tags: python, linux, terminal

Most of the [code samples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/termios.html#example) I've seen are trying to read from stdin without local echo. To do this they modify the ["local modes"](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) flag to remove the [setting to "Echo input characters"](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html). I thought I could just modify the "input modes" flag to `TIOCSTI` which is for ["Insert the given byte in the input queue."](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty_ioctl.4.html). However, even though I run the script as root, it has no effect. anything I write to the fd seems to go to the terminal output, rather than the terminal input. Basically what I want to do is [this exact thing](https://gist.github.com/RichardBronosky/62a4fc8531a169abb811#file-writevt-c-L53-L59), but in pure python.

```
"""
termfake.py

Usage: sudo python termfake.py /dev/ttys002

Get the tty device path of a different local termimal by running `tty`
in that terminal.
"""

import sys
import termios

fd = open(sys.argv[1], 'w')
fdno = fd.fileno()

# Returns [iflag, oflag, cflag, lflag, ispeed, ospeed, cc]
tatters = termios.tcgetattr(fdno)
print('original', tatters)
tatters[0] = termios.TIOCSTI
print('TIOCSTI', termios.TIOCSTI)

# Set iflag
termios.tcsetattr(fdno, termios.TCSANOW, tatters)

# Verify setting change
with open('/dev/ttys002', 'w') as fd2:
    print('modified', termios.tcgetattr(fd2.fileno()))

fd.write('This is test\n')
fd.close()
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`TIOCSTI` is an ioctl (documented in [tty_ioctl(4)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty_ioctl.4.html)), not a terminal setting, so you can't use `tcsetattr()` -- you need to feed each character of the fake input to `ioctl()` instead. Never had to do ioctl's from Python before, but the following seems to work for running an `ls` in a different terminal (specified as the argument, e.g. */dev/pts/13*) that's running Bash:

```
import fcntl
import sys
import termios

with open(sys.argv[1], 'w') as fd:
    for c in "ls\n":
        fcntl.ioctl(fd, termios.TIOCSTI, c)
```

`TIOCSTI` requires root privileges (or `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` to be more specific, but that's usually the same in practice) by the way -- see [capabilities(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for this! This works perfectly. I did find fcntl when searching for for "python ioctl" since ioctl was used in the C example. I didn't understand how the first example I found applied to me and forgot to go back and study it more.

Answer (score 6):

I took the answer from @Ulfalizer and expanded it a bit to be a complete and usable app.

```
import sys
import fcntl
import termios
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('tty', type=argparse.FileType('w'),
                    help='full tty path as given by the tty command')
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('-n', action='store_true',
                   help='prevent sending a trailing newline character')
group.add_argument('--stdin', action='store_true',
                   help='read input from stdin')
group = parser.add_argument_group()
group.add_argument('cmd', nargs='?',
                    help='command to run (required if not using --stdin)')
group.add_argument('args', nargs='*',
                    help='arguments to command')
args = parser.parse_known_args()

if args.stdin:
    data = sys.stdin.read()
else:
    data = ' '.join([args.cmd] + args.args)

for c in data:
    fcntl.ioctl(args.tty, termios.TIOCSTI, c)
if not args.n and data[-1][-1] != '\n':
    fcntl.ioctl(args.tty, termios.TIOCSTI, '\n')
```

Here is how you use it:

**Terminal #1:** do...

```
$ tty > /tmp/t1
```

**Terminal #2:** do...

```
$ sudo python termfake.py $(cat /tmp/t1) date +%s
```

**Terminal #1:** observe...

```
$ tty > /tmp/t1
$ date +%s
1487276400
```