# Sending key to specific window python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ctypes

I was wondering if I could send a keystroke to a program I'm not currently in. For example: notepad using cmd. There are two answers I have seen so far which are similar

- [This one did not get any answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39304191/sending-key-presses-to-a-specific-window-in-windows-in-python)
- [This one is similar, but I am not sure how to apply it to my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906925/python-simulate-keydown)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: OK, but have **you** tried (and what are the problems you encountered)? Check [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @CristiFati I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996985/send-some-keys-to-inactive-window-with-python), and it was just what I was looking for. I just now need to know how I do instead of notepad, chrome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to fake terminal input with termios.TIOCSTI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29614264/unable-to-fake-terminal-input-with-termios-tiocsti)